# angular2 - route to component based on external query param

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

How can I configure my router to support redirect based on some query string?
consider the following scenario:
the app sends an email with code validation, i'd like the user to click on the email and go to specific component. (e.g -  http://some.site.com/activate?code=XXX) should go to ActivateComponent and the code as input.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, Try below,

```
Route,
 { path: 'activate', component: ActivateComponent  }

@Component({
   selector: 'activate',
   template: `
     <h1>{{code | async}}</h1>
   `
  })
export class ActivateComponent  {
  code = "";
 constructor(private router: Router) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  // Capture the code if available
    this.code = this.router
     .routerState
     .queryParams
     .map(params => params['code'] || 'None');
  }
}
```

and where ever you want to go to this path, you can have some function similar to below,

```
  gotoLink = () =>{
     let navigationExtras = {
       queryParams: { 'code': 'XXX' }
     };

     this.router.navigate(['/activate'], navigationExtras);
  }
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cy2wGy2K0y3UnzSTrZQ8?p=preview)

Comment: you can also do it in HTML something like this:
 [routerLink]="['/activate', { code: 'XXX' }]"

Comment: Thanks,  I actually wanted to know how can I auto redirect from the AppComponent, assuming he the first one to get the request even If i go to http://some.url/some-component?code=mycode but i've implemented your suggestion in the ActivateComponent and looks like it's working..